# Average distance of 1s electron from nucleus in He⁺ ion

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure

> What would be the average value of $r$, i.e.  $\langle r\rangle$, in the $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of $\ce{He+}?$
> $$
> \text{a}.~\frac{3}{2}a_0 \qquad
> \text{b}.~\frac{3}{4}a_0  \qquad
> \text{c}.~3a_0  \qquad
> \text{d}.~\frac{1}{2}a_0
> $$

I have written the normalized wavefunction of $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of $\ce{He+}:$

$$R_{(1,0)} = \frac{2 \sqrt 2}{\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}} \times a^{-2r/a_0},$$

but I could not proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average value of $r$ can be found out, in case of $\text s$ orbitals by multiplying the volume of each thin spherical shell by the probability density at that $r$ and adding them up.

This can simply be accomplished by using integration as a limit of sum. We know that the probability density $\mathrm dP/\mathrm dV = R^2$. So,

$$
\begin{align}
⟨r⟩ &= \int_0^\infty r\,\mathrm dP \\
⟨r⟩ &= \int_0^\infty rR^2\,\mathrm {d}V\\
⟨r⟩ &= \int_0^\infty r\left(\frac{2 \sqrt 2}{\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}} \times e^{-2r/a_0}\right)^2\left(4\pi r^2\,\mathrm {d}r\right)\\
⟨r⟩ &= \frac{3a_0}{4}\\
\end{align}
$$